# Prove that any quantum theory only has symmetry transformations of unitary and antiunitary types

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, symmetry, unitarity

In p.289 of Sakurai's book on modern quantum mechanics (the latest edition):

> In order for (4.410) to be satisfied, it is of physical interests to consider just two types of transformations---unitary or anti-unitary. Other possibilities are related to either of the preceding via trivial phase changes. The proof of this assertion is actually very difficult and will not be discussed here. See *Quantum Mechanics: Fundamentals Kurt Gottfried, Tung-Mow Yan (2003)*.

I believe that he meant to consider the transformation acts on the states in the Hilbert space, say:
$$|a\rangle \to |\tilde{a}\rangle $$
$$|b\rangle  \to |\tilde{b}\rangle $$

We demand the transformation is indeed a symmetry
of the system if it obeys (the (4.410) of Sakurai book):
$$|\langle b|a\rangle | = |\langle \tilde{b}|\tilde{a}\rangle|.$$

**My question** is that how to give such a proof (sorry, I do not have Gottfried-Yan (2003))? And does this imply that we *prove that any quantum theory only has symmetry transformations of unitary and antiunitary types? Only unitary symmetries or antiunitary symmetries?*

Comment: For the love of god, please, use \ langle and \rangle if you use bras and kets. Another reference perhaps handy for Bargmann's proof of Wigner's theorem is here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/342251/

Answer (score 6):

This is the statement of *Wigner's theorem*.  You can find (apparently two) proofs of Wigner's theorem [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0808.0779).

The broad summary is as follows.  First, (pure) states are **not** elements of the Hilbert space $\mathcal H$.  The set of physical states $\Sigma$ can be defined as the *equivalence classes* of $\mathcal H$ under the equivalence relation $\sim$, where $\psi \sim \phi \iff$ there exists some nonzero $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ such that $\phi=\lambda \psi$.

Let $\Phi,\Psi$ be elements of $\Sigma$.  We define the ray product $(\Phi,\Psi)$ by choosing any two representatives $\phi$ and $\psi$ of $\Phi$ and $\Psi$, and defining
$$(\Phi,\Psi) := \frac{|\langle \phi,\psi\rangle|}{\Vert \phi\Vert \Vert \psi \Vert}$$

Having made this definition, it turns out that the mathematical predictions of the theory - decay rates, the probabilities of various measurement outcomes, etc - can be expressed in terms of ray products of physical states.  Therefore, a symmetry transformation $T:\Sigma\rightarrow\Sigma$ is a bijective transformation on the space of physical states which leaves all ray products invariant, i.e. $(T\Phi,T\Psi)=(\Phi,\Psi)$.

Given some operator $\hat A$ on the Hilbert space, we can induce a corresponding transformation $\underline A$ on $\Sigma$ in the natural way.  Furthermore, if $\hat U$ is a unitary or antiunitary operator on $\mathcal H$, one can see right away that $\underline U$ is a **symmetry transformation** on $\Sigma$, because

$$(\underline U\Phi,\underline U\Psi) := \frac{|\langle \hat U\phi,\hat U\psi\rangle|}{\Vert \hat U\phi\Vert \Vert \hat U\psi\Vert} = \frac{|\langle \phi,\psi\rangle|}{\Vert \phi\Vert \Vert \psi \Vert} = (\Phi,\Psi)$$

Note also that this association between operators on $\mathcal H$ and maps on $\Sigma$ is not one-to-one.  Multiple different operators may induce precisely the same map. For example, the identity operator on $\mathcal H$ and the operator $\psi \mapsto e^{i\theta} \psi$ **both** induce the identity transformation on $\Sigma$ because they map all of the equivalence classes to themselves.

---

With these preliminaries out of the way, Wigner's theorem is a pseudo-converse of the above.  It turns out that **any** symmetry transformation on $\Sigma$ can be induced by *some* unitary or antiunitary operator on $\mathcal H$. That doesn't mean that *only* (anti)unitary operators induce symmetry transformations, but rather that if some operator $\hat A$ induces a symmetry transformation, then we can find a unitary or antiunitary operator $\hat U$ which induces the same transformation.  As a result, it is *sufficient* to restrict your attention to (anti)unitary operators.

Incidentally, this is also why we are interested in projective representations of groups, c.f. my related answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/632093/156895).

Comment: Thanks I voted up

Comment: @anniemarieheart If I answered your question, you can accept the answer by ticking the box next to it.  If I haven't, feel free to clarify your question.

Comment: I will be happy to accept in a few days if no better answers! (p.s. I asked a new question maybe you also know.)