# Symmetry and corresponding operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, topological-phase

For a quantum symmetry, is the operator of symmetry necessary to be unitary?

Comment: Can you give some more information about your question?

Comment: More or less, it can also be anti-unitary like in the case of time reversal symmetry. You’ll need to precisely define what is a symmetry in the context of QM. Check out Wigner’s theorem for more information:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_theorem

Comment: @ Brendan Darrer. @
lpz For example, the chiral and inverse symmetry operators are unitary, and the Time-reversal and particle-hole operators are anti-unitary. Can I say that there is symmetry such that C H C^\dagger=H with operators that is neither unitary nor anti-unitary?

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/636053/49107